# Used 40 votes today for the first time but did not earn badge that goes with it.

Tags: support

Is this just a bug or am I missing something?  Or is there some sort of delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there may be a short delay.

You [received the badge](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/2876/balanced-mama?tab=activity&sort=badges) at 3:57:27, about five minutes after you cast your last vote (and actually before you asked this question).